# Upsert function in TypeORM

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, upsert

I am trying to implement upsert functionality to avoid redundant data into the database. Mentioned below is the schema that I have created.

```
@Entity({ name: 'tokens' })
export class Token {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    public id: number;

    @Column({ type: 'varchar', name: 'email', default: null })
    public email: string;

    @Column({ type: 'text', name: 'token', nullable: false })
    public token: string;
    
    @Column({ type: 'varchar', name: 'code', nullable: false })
    public code: string;

    @Column({ type: 'varchar', name: 'type', nullable: false })
    public type: string;

    @Column({ type: 'varchar', name: 'status', default: STATUS.ACTIVE })
    public status: string;

    /**
     * Adding Create & Update Date Columns
     */
    @CreateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamp', name: 'created_at' })
    public createdAt: Date;

    @UpdateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamp', name: 'updated_at' })
    public updatedAt: Date;
}
```

In sequelize, I used unique property in "email" and "code" column and that helped me to write Upsert functionality.

I am new to TypeORM and Nest.js, I might have asked a dumb question but I am getting any solution for it.

What changes can I make in schema and what will be the upsert query for the above schema if I want to upsert values by making "email" and "type" as composite primary keys? Thank you so much in advance.

I am trying to implement Upsert in TypeORM.

Expected: To upsert values into the database based on "email" and "code"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `upsert` method of the [Repository API](https://typeorm.io/repository-api#:%7E:text=upsert%20-%20Inserts%20a,firstName%20%3D%20EXCLUDED.firstName%0A%20**%2F).

In your case, you need to create the unique composite index first to allow checking if inserts or updates are unique:

```js
@Entity({ name: 'tokens' })
@Unique('email_type', ['email', 'type'])
export class Token {
  // ...
}
```

With the index in place, you can then use it in your upsert queries:

```js
const token = {
  email: 'contact@example.com',
  type: 'password_reset',
  token: '...',
  code: '...',
};
await this.tokenRepository.upsert(token, ['email_type'])
```

Depending on what database you are using, the Query Builder `onConflict` method can also be used if you want more control over how upserts are handled.

Comment: I keep getting the following error: "Property \"token_type\" was not found in \"Token\". Make sure your query is correct". Could you please help!

I followed exactly what was demonstrated in the above answer

Comment: I got the solution: Instead of 
```
await this.tokenRepository.upsert(token, ['email_type'])
```

I had to use
```
await this.tokenRepository.upsert(token, ['email', 'type'])
```

Comment: Ok, it might be due to differences between databases. Did you have to create an index for it to work?